# JS method inside object -> Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, dictionary, methods

Not sure if this is an obvious answer or not, but I'm converting a JS object to a Swift dictionary and am uncertain how to handle methods nested inside the object.  Example:

```
TopLevel: {
        description: function () {
            return "Text to return"
        },
        upgradeDescription: function () {
            return "Text to return"
        },
        baseModifier: 0.01,
    }
```

My logic would say, write this as:

```
"TopLevel": [
    "description": func() {
        return "Text to return"
    },
    "upgradeDescription": func() {
        return "Text to return"
    },
    "baseModifier": 0.01
]
```

But Swift doesn't like that.  Appreciate thoughts.  For reference, I am trying to do this as a full conversion.  Please do not provide recommendations that involve leaving the JS alone and simply referencing it from the new Swift file.  This project will be 100% Swift.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like structs are the way to go rather than a nested dictionary.